# React/Gatsby/Wordpress stuck on "source and transform nodes"

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, gatsby

I know there's a couple of those questions out there already but most of them look closed or outdated...

We have a React/Gatsby site on local, which pulls blog posts and media from our prod WP hosted on WPEngine. Yesterday still, it was working fine, when calling **gatsby develop** it would start the local server in ~2 minutes. Today, for apparently no reason, it gives us the following :

```
C:\www\my_react_project>gatsby develop
success open and validate gatsby-config - 0.004 s
success load plugins - 0.195 s
success onPreInit - 0.605 s
success delete html and css files from previous builds - 0.368 s
success initialize cache - 3.565 s
success copy gatsby files - 0.267 s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.008 s
? source and transform nodes
=START PLUGIN=====================================

Site URL: https://somecorpsite.com
Site hosted on Wordpress.com: false
Using ACF: false
Using Auth: undefined undefined
Verbose output: true

Mama Route URL: https://somecorpsite.com/wp-json

? source and transform nodesRoute discovered : /
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/posts
Valid route found. Will try to fetch.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/posts/(?P<id>[\d]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/posts/(?P<parent>[\d]+)/revisions
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/posts/(?P<parent>[\d]+)/revisions/(?P<id>[\d]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/pages
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/pages/(?P<id>[\d]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/pages/(?P<parent>[\d]+)/revisions
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/pages/(?P<parent>[\d]+)/revisions/(?P<id>[\d]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/media
Valid route found. Will try to fetch.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/media/(?P<id>[\d]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/types
Valid route found. Will try to fetch.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/types/(?P<type>[\w-]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/statuses
Valid route found. Will try to fetch.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/statuses/(?P<status>[\w-]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/taxonomies
Valid route found. Will try to fetch.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/taxonomies/(?P<taxonomy>[\w-]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/categories
Valid route found. Will try to fetch.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/categories/(?P<id>[\d]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/tags
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/tags/(?P<id>[\d]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/yst_prominent_words
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/yst_prominent_words/(?P<id>[\d]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/users
Valid route found. Will try to fetch.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/users/(?P<id>[\d]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/users/me
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/comments
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/comments/(?P<id>[\d]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /wp/v2/settings
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /oembed/1.0
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /oembed/1.0/embed
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /oembed/1.0/proxy
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /yoast/v1
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /yoast/v1/configurator
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /yoast/v1/reindex_posts
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /yoast/v1/ryte
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /yoast/v1/indexables/(?P<object_type>.*)/(?P<object_id>\d+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /yoast/v1/statistics
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /acf/v3
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/posts/(?P<id>[\d]+)/?(?P<field>[\w\-\_]+)?
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/posts
Valid route found. Will try to fetch.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/pages/(?P<id>[\d]+)/?(?P<field>[\w\-\_]+)?
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/pages
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/media/(?P<id>[\d]+)/?(?P<field>[\w\-\_]+)?
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/media
Valid route found. Will try to fetch.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/categories/(?P<id>[\d]+)/?(?P<field>[\w\-\_]+)?
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/categories
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/tags/(?P<id>[\d]+)/?(?P<field>[\w\-\_]+)?
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/tags
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/yst_prominent_words/(?P<id>[\d]+)/?(?P<field>[\w\-\_]+)?
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/yst_prominent_words
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/comments/(?P<id>[\d]+)/?(?P<field>[\w\-\_]+)?
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/comments
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/options/(?P<id>[\w\-\_]+)/?(?P<field>[\w\-\_]+)?
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/users/(?P<id>[\d]+)/?(?P<field>[\w\-\_]+)?
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /acf/v3/users
Valid route found. Will try to fetch.
Route discovered : /yoast/v1/prominent_words
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /yoast/v1/prominent_words_link/(?P<id>[\d]+)
Invalid route.
Route discovered : /yoast/v1/complete_recalculation
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /yoast/v1/link_suggestions
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.
Route discovered : /yoast/v1/redirects
Excluded route from excludedRoutes pattern.

Fetching the JSON data from 10 valid API Routes...

=== [ Fetching wordpress__POST ] === https://somecorpsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
? source and transform nodes
Total entities : 235
Pages to be requested : 3
? source and transform nodes -> wordpress__POST fetched : 235
Fetching the wordpress__POST took: 17352.127ms

=== [ Fetching wordpress__wp_media ] === https://somecorpsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media
? source and transform nodes
Total entities : 4638
Pages to be requested : 47
? source and transform nodes -> wordpress__wp_media fetched : 3212
Fetching the wordpress__wp_media took: 73903.345ms

=== [ Fetching wordpress__wp_types ] === https://somecorpsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types
? source and transform nodes -> wordpress__wp_types fetched : 1
Fetching the wordpress__wp_types took: 875.090ms

=== [ Fetching wordpress__wp_statuses ] === https://somecorpsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/statuses
? source and transform nodes -> wordpress__wp_statuses fetched : 1
Fetching the wordpress__wp_statuses took: 852.903ms

=== [ Fetching wordpress__wp_taxonomies ] === https://somecorpsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies
? source and transform nodes -> wordpress__wp_taxonomies fetched : 1
Fetching the wordpress__wp_taxonomies took: 1083.236ms

=== [ Fetching wordpress__CATEGORY ] === https://somecorpsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories
? source and transform nodes -> wordpress__CATEGORY fetched : 9
Fetching the wordpress__CATEGORY took: 1433.496ms

=== [ Fetching wordpress__wp_users ] === https://somecorpsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users
? source and transform nodes -> wordpress__wp_users fetched : 14
Fetching the wordpress__wp_users took: 1790.912ms

=== [ Fetching wordpress__acf_posts ] === https://somecorpsite.com/wp-json/acf/v3/posts
? source and transform nodes -> wordpress__acf_posts fetched : 100
Fetching the wordpress__acf_posts took: 5476.182ms

=== [ Fetching wordpress__acf_media ] === https://somecorpsite.com/wp-json/acf/v3/media
? source and transform nodes -> wordpress__acf_media fetched : 95
Fetching the wordpress__acf_media took: 6159.952ms

=== [ Fetching wordpress__acf_users ] === https://somecorpsite.com/wp-json/acf/v3/users
? source and transform nodes -> wordpress__acf_users fetched : 14
Fetching the wordpress__acf_users took: 16257.418ms

=END PLUGIN=====================================: 126446.712ms
? source and transform nodes
```

...and then it gets stuck on the **source and transform nodes**. I've let it try to do its thing for over an hour before killing it.

As far as we know, nothing's changed in the configs or GraphQL bits on our React project. There's been one new blog post posted on our WP site this morning, but how could it prevent Gatsby from running ?

Also, the fact that it freezes after the END OF PLUGINS, doesn't it mean that the bug is not on the WP side ? Gatsby at that point is done fetching things from WP, correct ?

As I said I know similar questions have been asked before. But none of the answers I've seen seem complete or seem to really address our situation.

If it helps, here's our dependencies :

```
"gatsby": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
"gatsby-cli": "^2.4.3",
"gatsby-image": "next",
"gatsby-paginate": "^1.0.16",
"gatsby-plugin-catch-links": "next",
"gatsby-plugin-google-fonts": "^0.0.4",
"gatsby-plugin-manifest": "next",
"gatsby-plugin-netlify": "next",
"gatsby-plugin-nprogress": "next",
"gatsby-plugin-offline": "next",
"gatsby-plugin-page-transitions": "^1.0.7",
"gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "next",
"gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
"gatsby-plugin-sharp": "next",
"gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "next",
"gatsby-remark-autolink-headers": "next",
"gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.7",
"gatsby-source-hubspot": "^1.0.0",
"gatsby-source-stripe": "latest",
"gatsby-source-wordpress": "^2.0.93",
"gatsby-transformer-remark": "next",
"gatsby-transformer-sharp": "next",
"graphql": "^0.13.2",
"hashmap": "^2.3.0",
"i18n-react": "^0.6.4",
"node-sass": "^4.9.3",
"opentracing": "^0.14.3",
"react": "^16.5.2",
"react-dom": "^16.5.2",
"react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
"react-hubspot-form": "^1.3.6",
"react-md": "^1.5.0",
"typeface-roboto": "^0.0.54",
"utf8": "^3.0.0",
"yarn": "^1.9.4"
```

Thanks for any input !

Comment: Seems weird that this would happen all of a sudden. I'd try updating your WP source plugin?? They are currently on 3.0.12 https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-source-wordpress

Seems to be related to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951965/gatsby-source-wordpress-doesnt-finish-running) but no one answered that either...

Answer (score 1):

Try resizing your terminal. I know... it's weird but it's the fix for most people. - See here https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4666

Comment: Thanks man. Very weird issue. Any idea on why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody suggested to me that this was a memory problem with node. I put the following in the terminal and it fixed the problem for me:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```